# Merge three columns in one (linux, python, or perl)

Tags: linux, csv, merge, columnsorting, vcftools

I have one file (.tsv) that contain variants calling for all the samples. I would like to merge the first three columns into one column:

Example:
Original:

file name= variants.tsv > the first three columns that I want to merge are:

lane    sampleID        Barcode

B31     00-00-NNA-0000      0000

Desired output:

ID

B31_00-00-NNA-0000_0000

what are the recommended methods?

Comment: `tr ' ' '_' < YourFile.tsv` maybe?

Comment: Are there more columns you don't want merged together?

Answer (score 0):

One way, with a perl one-liner:

```sh
perl -F'\t' -lane '
    if ($. == 1) {
        print join("\t", "ID", @F[3..$#F])
    } else {
        print join("\t", join("_", @F[0,1,2]), @F[3..$#F])
    }' variants tsv
```

Splits each line into an array (`@F`) on tabs, and prints out the header and later lines using [slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices) of that array to extract the appropriate elements, which are then joined into delimited strings.

Comment: Using the term "one-liner" loosely, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this

```
lane    sampleID    Barcode
B31 00-00-NNA-0000  0000
```

and using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), you can run

```sh
mlr --tsv put -S '$ID=$lane."_".$sampleID."_".$Barcode' input.tsv >output.tsv
```

to have

```
+------+----------------+---------+-------------------------+
| lane | sampleID       | Barcode | ID                      |
+------+----------------+---------+-------------------------+
| B31  | 00-00-NNA-0000 | 0000    | B31_00-00-NNA-0000_0000 |
+------+----------------+---------+-------------------------+
```

If you want only the ID field the command is

```
mlr --tsv put -S '$ID=$lane."_".$sampleID."_".$Barcode' then cut -f ID input.tsv >output.tsv
```